# Random cipher from a friend

Tags: cipher

Below is what I have. I know that X is padding, and I've tried ROT1-25. I assume it's substitution, but I don't see it.

TUAUC IHCRN OSELL CDXNE AHEX

Answer (score 17):

The message is very short, but a cursory frequency analysis tells you that ...

> ... the letter distribution isn't far from the distribution in English texts: E is the most frequent letter, along with C. There are some Ls, some Hs to go with the Cs, and so on. This is more likely a transposition cipher than a substitution cipher.

The first letter is T and ...

> ... if you look at the second letter of the second block and the third letter of the third block, they are H and E, which conventiently spells THE. Rearrange the letters in a rectangle of width 6:
>
> ```
> T U A U C I
> H C R N O S
> E L L C D X
> N E A H E X
> ```
>
> You can now read the message column-wise from top to bottom.

The message reads:

> *The nuclear launch code is XX.*

Use it wisely. `:)`

Comment: Lies! Everybody knows the [nuclear launch code is `00000000`](https://www.google.com/search?q=nuclear+launch+code+00000000).